# TableAlignments -> Left not working

Tags: output-formatting, bugs, list-manipulation

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0.**

---

For a very simple dataset `TableAlignments->Left` does not work:

```
table = {{"chi1", {0.5732772714880409`, 0.37224553853824593`, 
    0.4406080034309774`}}, {"chi2", {0.11746301802400358`, 
    0.2410578341291309`, 
    0.20673964872863448`}}, {"chi3", {Missing["Only 1 points"], 
    Missing["Only 1 points"]}}, {"chi4", {0.05693578150660176`, 
    0.06300145309006996`, 
    0.09833005450944177`}}, {"chi5", {0.08916843025621737`, 
    0.07612462967770783`, 0.05993923221739268`}}}
tableImage = 
 TableForm[table, 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"Dihedral", "\[Tau] per state [ns]"}}, 
  TableAlignments -> Left]
```

[image: Wrong output]

`TableAlignments->Right` seems to work

[image: Correct right-aligned output]

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The Problem

I believe this is a bug in `TableForm`.  We can see by looking at the Box form of the output that the option `ColumnAlignments` of the outermost `GridBox` does not behave as it should.

```
tab = {{1, {1, 1, 1}}, {2, {2, 2, 2}}, {3, {3, 3, 3}}, {4, {4, 4, 4}}};

getOption = Options[First@ToBoxes@#, ColumnAlignments] &;

tForm =
 TableForm[tab, 
   TableHeadings -> {None, {"Title 1", "Title 2"}}, 
   TableAlignments -> #] &;

Table[
  {ali, getOption @ tForm @ ali},
  {ali, {Left, Center, Right, Top, Bottom}}
] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see this option tracks `TableAlignments` for every value *except* `Left`.

---

#### A solution

Since this answer is not complete without a work-around:

```
fix =
  DisplayForm @ Replace[
    ToBoxes @ #,
    (ca : ColumnAlignments -> _) :> (ca -> Left),
    {2}
  ] &;

fix @ tableImage
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

#### A fix to load at startup

Here are two options for a fix suitable for inclusion in your `init.m` file.

**Method #1**

This is just packaging the simple fix above.  It could be problematic because it forces evaluation of `TableForm` into boxes, when `TableForm` normally acts as a wrapper.  For this reason method #2 should be used if possible.

```
Unprotect[TableForm];

x : TableForm[__, TableAlignments -> Left | {Left, _}, ___] :=
  Replace[
    MakeBoxes @ x,
    (ca : ColumnAlignments -> _) :> (ca -> Left),
    {2}
  ] // DisplayForm

Protect[TableForm];
```

**Method #2**

This is considerably more verbose, but it works at the *correct* level (`MakeBoxes`).
However, it may be a bit fragile:  when a `TableForm` expression is first displayed (or explicitly sent to `MakeBoxes`) certain additional definitions are loaded internally.  I use such an explicit call, add my definition, and then modify the order of the FormatValues of `TableForm`.  Should there be some other internal initialization that resets the FormatValues or changes their order this fix will be lost.  It is important that this code not be evaluated twice in one session or the FormatValues will be out of order and the fix will fail.

```
Unprotect[TableForm]

TableForm[{}] // ToBoxes; (* pre-load TableForm's FormatValues; do not remove! *)

MakeBoxes[x : TableForm[__, opts : OptionsPattern[]], _] /; ! TrueQ[tfAlignLeftFix] :=
  Block[{tfAlignLeftFix = True},
    Replace[MakeBoxes@x, (ca : ColumnAlignments -> _) :> (ca -> Left), {2}]
  ] /; MatchQ[OptionValue[TableForm, {opts}, TableAlignments], Left | {Left, _}]

FormatValues@TableForm = RotateRight@FormatValues@TableForm;

Protect[TableForm]
```

This method also adds robust detection of the alignment option, e.g. including those set with `Options[TableForm] = . . .` and of the form `TableForm[_, {options}]`.

Comment: Could you comment on how the last fix works? Here is what I understand: Any time it sees a `TableForm` with `TableAlignments->Left` it converts the expression to boxes and replaces the `ColumnAlignmets`, then it converts this back to DisplayForm. What is the purpose of `x:` and `/;`? `x` is probably the whole matched expression and the conditional assignment is there to prevent recursion?

Comment: @Ajasja You got it right.  All of it.  Well done. :-)  (ps. sorry for the ironic out-of-alignment code; that's a bug with `$` that I have reported on Meta.)

Comment: Thanks. But what could cause recursion? Nested `TableForm`s?

Comment: @Ajasja Yes.  Since `x` is the original function call to `TableForm` unchanged and it is given to `ToBoxes` within the fix, without the `Block` this would again match the pattern given and start an infinite recursion.  There are other ways around this problem but this one is nice and clean.  I learned it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/618728).

Comment: @Ajasja your recent reference (thanks) make me look at this answer again, and I now realize that Gayley-Villegas recursion protection is overkill, as a simple `Unevaluated@x` works also.  Further, I believe we can simple use `MakeBoxes` as this *already* holds its arguments.  I shall update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but you know I can't give you another +1 :)

Comment: @Ajasja This answer was rushed before.  I've given it some proper consideration this time, and added **Method #2** which I believe will be much more appropriate for actual use.  Should it fail I left the first method for reference.

Answer (score 8):

For some reason, your nested data rows throw off the alignment. If you `Column` your second entries, you get this:

```
table[[All, 2]] = Column /@ table[[All, 2]];
TableForm[table, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Dihedral", "\[Tau] per state [ns]"}}, 
 TableAlignments -> {Left}]
```

[image: Correct output]

Personally, I mostly switched over to `Grid` because it is more versatile, but of course `TableForm` is still supported and useful...

Comment: @Ajasja Thanks for the prettifying edit. I prefer to include small amounts of raw data in the code snippet for ease of use. All the other posters seem to go along with `table` directly, so I am the odd one out there.

Comment: You're welcome. Also I agree with the last sentence. I think I'll have to switch over to `Grid` as well.

Comment: @Ajasja Nesting `Grid`s works really quite nicely in a lot of cases...

Answer (score 7):

The following modification of your code gives what you expect:

```
TableForm[Map[TableForm[#, TableAlignments -> Left] &, table, {2}], 
TableHeadings -> {None, {"Dihedral", "\[Tau] per state [ns]"}}, 
TableAlignments -> Left]
```

[image]

EDIT: A variation applying `Column` to the second elements of the lists (as in @Yves's answer):

```
TableForm[Map[{First@#,Column @@ Rest[#]}&, table], 
TableHeadings -> {None, {"Dihedral", "\[Tau] per state [ns]"}}, 
TableAlignments -> Left]
```

Answer (score 5):

The trouble seems to be with the headings specification:

```
TableForm[table, TableAlignments -> Left]
```

seems to work fine.

Adding the headings as an element to the table will work:

```
Prepend[table, {"Dihedral", "\[Tau] per state [ns]"}] // TableForm
```

or

```
 TableForm[Prepend[table, {"Dihedral", "\[Tau] per state [ns]"}],TableAlignments -> Left]
```

Produce,

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As soon as you add the column headings it stops working as expected. For example: `TableForm[List /@ table[[All, 2]], 
 TableHeadings -> {table[[All, 1]], {"\[Tau] per state [ns]"}}]`

Comment: And it only breaks for the default option of Left alignment and works for Right and Center.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is aligning correctly, i.e. each block corresponding to your `chi`s.
For instance, with `TableAlignments -> Right` the last entry corresponding to `chi2` is not aligned.
If you flatten them you get what you'd expect :

```
mydata = Flatten[table[[All, 2]]];
TableForm[Transpose[{Range[Length[mydata]], mydata}], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"Dihedral", "\[Tau] per state [ns]"}}, 
  TableAlignments -> {Left}]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to keep the values grouped together.