# FindFit returns worse result when putting constraints on parameters

Tags: fitting

I want to fit some data to a model of exponential decay using the `FindFit` function:

```
data = {{0, 78}, {24, 64.5}, {48, 70.5}, {96, 54}, {144, 64.5}, {216, 3}, {336, 0}, {696, 0}};
model = data[[1, 2]]*Exp[-k1*t];

fit1 = FindFit[data, model, k1, t]
fit2 = FindFit[data, {model, k1 > 0}, k1, t]

modelf1 = Function[{t}, Evaluate[model /. fit1]];
modelf2 = Function[{t}, Evaluate[model /. fit2]];

Plot[#[t], {t, 0, 696}, Epilog -> Map[Point, data], PlotRange -> All] & /@ {modelf1, modelf2}
```

Interestingly, the model with no specified constraint on *k1* finds a much better solution than the constrained model, but the solution of the unconstrained problem falls within the range of the constrained one. Here is the output:

---

```
{k1 -> 0.00512571}
{k1 -> 1.01979}
```

[image: Result of the Plot]

Why isn't the solution to the constrained problem at least as good as the solution of the unconstrained one?

Comment: I think the reason is that different methods are used for constrained and unconstrained problems.

Comment: Have you tried: `fit2 = FindFit[data, {model, k1 > 0}, k1, t, Method -> NMinimize]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because your constraint forces the path chosen for finding a local extrema.
You could verify it by doing:

```
data ={{0, 78}, {24, 64.5}, {48, 70.5}, {96, 54}, {144, 64.5}, {216, 3}, {336, 0}, {696, 0}};
model = data[[1, 2]]*Exp[-k1*t];
l = {}; l1 = {};
fit1 = FindFit[data,  model, k1,          t, EvaluationMonitor :> AppendTo[l, k1]]
fit2 = FindFit[data, {model, k1 > 0}, k1, t, EvaluationMonitor :> AppendTo[l1, k1]]

Show[ListLinePlot[{l1,l}], 
         ListPlot[{l1,l},PlotStyle ->{{Blue,PointSize[Large]}, {Red,PointSize[Medium]}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

As for why some methods fail, you can see your extrema is very sharp:

```
f[k1_] := Total[(data[[1, 2]]*Exp[-k1*#[[1]]] - #[[2]])^2 & /@ data];
Plot[{f[k1], Evaluate[D[f[k2], k2] /. k2 -> k1]}, {k1, -1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-.1, .4}, {0, 16500}}, Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: But it does not explain why the Automatic option for the constrained problem uses another path then the constrained "NMinimize" option? Just add l2={} and fit3 = FindFit[data, {model,k1>0}, k1, t, Method->"NMinimize",EvaluationMonitor :> AppendTo[l2, k1]] to your code.

Comment: @FrederikZiebell as far as I can see, you are not asking that in your question

Comment: You should start another career as function counselor and help all those solutions come to terms with their shyness (or [aichmophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aichmophobia))

Comment: @YvesKlett Function shyness is deeply studied by psycho-math-analysts, [including real and imaginary shyness problems](http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-International-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0070542341)

Comment: @belisarius If you are only interested in values for a fit parameter for a given range, say 0 to 1, is it possible to allow *FindFit* to look or start outside of that range, say at 1.1, but ignore all results outside of that range?  I'm currently facing this problem because I want to fit a parameter within a specified range, but *NMinimize* fails if I try to impose that range and *Method->Automatic* leads to fit parameters that do not appear to be as good as *NMinimize*.  If I open the range wider, *FindFit* only finds the result outside of the range I really care about.  What do you suggest?

Comment: @iwantmyphd Difficult to say without taking a look at the actual model and data. Why don't you post a question?

Comment: @belisarius Would you consider this a separate question?  This seems more like a clarification to the existing one.  Regarding the code, if need be, I can post a new question, but in my mind, the crux of it is being able to define boundaries for the solution without boundaries for the search itself, which would be independent of the data/model/etc.

Answer (score 13):

Different methods are used for constrained and unconstrained problems.
Compare for example

```
data = {{0, 78}, {24, 64.5}, {48, 70.5}, {96, 54}, {144, 64.5}, {216, 
    3}, {336, 0}, {696, 0}};
model = data[[1, 2]]*Exp[-k1*t];
methods = {Automatic, "ConjugateGradient", "Gradient", 
          "LevenbergMarquardt", "Newton", "QuasiNewton",
         {"NMinimize", Method -> "NelderMead"},
         {"NMinimize", Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}, 
         {"NMinimize", Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"},
         {"NMinimize", Method -> "RandomSearch"} };


fit1 = FindFit[data, model, k1, t, Method -> #] & /@ methods;
fit2 = (FindFit[data, {model, k1 > 0}, k1, t, Method -> #] & /@ methods) \
       /. FindFit[__] -> "NA";

TableForm[Transpose@{fit1, fit2}, TableAlignments -> Left, 
          TableHeadings -> {methods, {"Unconstrained", "Constrained"}}]
```

[image: output]

Note the warnings of the type `Method -> XXX can only be used for unconstrained problems`.

We see that `NMinimize` was the only method suitable for this constrained problem. For the unconstrained problem the `"Gradient"` method was probably used.

Oh, and if you want the table LeftAlignment to actually work, check out [this great answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7848/745).

Comment: Add the option "Automatic" to your `methods` variable and you see the thing that makes me wonder: Why does the Automatic method for the unconstrained problem find the value k1 -> 1.01979 when "NMinimize" is the only method available?

Comment: @FrederikZiebell I always thought "Automatic" just means that mma chooses the method for you. But in this case it seems something more is happening. No idea for now.

Comment: Didn't see this answer until now. +1. Two methods are missing: `"InteriorPoint"` and `{"NMinimize", Method -> "NonlinearInteriorPoint"}`. `FindFit` does not like to use these and spits out a lot of errors, but does return a result in both cases. Anyway, it shows that `Automatic` corresponds to `"InteriorPoint"` for the constrained problem in this case (and, I think, actually in general as well).