# ODE fitting to dataset

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

So, I have a ODE system, it is a complex biochemical kinetic mechanism with six species changing over time.

```
S'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k2 ES[t],
Eu'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k6 EP[t] + k2 ES[t],
ES'[t] == k1 Eu[t] S[t] - (k2 + k3) ES[t],
EP'[t] == k3 ES[t] - (k4 + k6) EP[t],
Ec'[t] == k4 EP[t],
P'[t] == k6 EP[t],
```

with the initial conditions:

```
S[0] == 100, Eu[0] == 0.5, ES[0] == 0, EP[0] == 0, Ec[0] == 0, 
P[0] == 0
```

I can solve the ODE system using NDSolve and manipulate it to "manually" fit some experimental data. Now, I have data for two species, and I want to numerically fit my ODE to those. I know three constants k1 (20),k2 (200) and k3 (0.03). I followed the approach described elsewhere, transforming my data in this way:

```
data = List[dataEP, dataEc];

transformedData = {ConstantArray[Range@Length[data], Length[time]] //Transpose, ConstantArray[time, Length[data]], data}~Flatten~{{2, 3}, {1}};
```

and then:

```
Sol = model[k3_?NumericQ, k4_?NumericQ, k6_?NumericQ, i_, te_] := ({EP[te], Ec[te]} /. First[NDSolve[ {
S'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k2 ES[t],
Eu'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k6 EP[t] + k2 ES[t],
ES'[t] == k1 Eu[t] S[t] - (k2 + k3) ES[t],
EP'[t] == k3 ES[t] - (k4 + k5 + k6) EP[t],
Ec'[t] == k4 EP[t],
Ed'[t] == k5 EP[t] ,
P'[t] == k6 EP[t], 
S[0] == 100, Eu[0] == 0.5, ES[0] == 0, EP[0] == 0, Ec[0] == 0, P[0] == 0}, {S, Eu, ES, EP, Ec, P}, {t, 0, 2000}, 
  Method -> Automatic, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
  PrecisionGoal -> Infinity]])
```

and then using NonlinearModelFit as following:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[transformedData, {model[k3, k4, k6][i, t]},{k3, k4, k6}, {i, t}]
```

> However, the fitting is really bad. I think the problem is that a) the fitting is not passing through the solver; b) maybe the fitting protocol is not identifying correctly EP and Ec. Another issue is that is not possible to get RSquared and other fitting options. Any help? I tried a lot of different setting and scripts, mostly following this forum. Thanks!!

Here an example of transformed data (i=1 is Ec and i=2 EP):

```
{{1, 0., 0.00001}, {1, 60.782, 0.01839}, {1, 121.43, 0.0273516}, {1, 
  182.062, 0.05744}, {1, 242.684, 0.066366}, {1, 303.31, 
  0.0834534}, {1, 363.983, 0.0966352}, {1, 424.626, 0.109041}, {1, 
  485.294, 0.124628}, {1, 545.964, 0.129099}, {1, 606.626, 
  0.133582}, {1, 667.293, 0.131262}, {1, 727.959, 0.142481}, {1, 
  788.619, 0.147817}, {1, 849.291, 0.145241}, {1, 909.936, 
  0.14883}, {1, 970.61, 0.154498}, {1, 1031.34, 0.151261}, {1, 
  1092.01, 0.155667}, {1, 1152.71, 0.15563}, {1, 1213.45, 
  0.148236}, {1, 1274.18, 0.15006}, {1, 1334.93, 0.161015}, {1, 
  1395.76, 0.158383}, {1, 1456.59, 0.167894}, {1, 1517.42, 
  0.165273}, {1, 1578.28, 0.170253}, {1, 1639.24, 0.166955}, {1, 
  1700.05, 0.160558}, {1, 1760.98, 0.161363}, {2, 0., 0.00001}, {2, 
  60.782, 0.233408}, {2, 121.43, 0.259436}, {2, 182.062, 
  0.224185}, {2, 242.684, 0.210032}, {2, 303.31, 0.175457}, {2, 
  363.983, 0.169942}, {2, 424.626, 0.163133}, {2, 485.294, 
  0.137899}, {2, 545.964, 0.116932}, {2, 606.626, 0.126436}, {2, 
  667.293, 0.108688}, {2, 727.959, 0.101772}, {2, 788.619, 
  0.0972984}, {2, 849.291, 0.0936195}, {2, 909.936, 0.0893072}, {2, 
  970.61, 0.0889732}, {2, 1031.34, 0.0737908}, {2, 1092.01, 
  0.0348883}, {2, 1152.71, 0.0796826}, {2, 1213.45, 0.0529935}, {2, 
  1274.18, 0.046321}, {2, 1334.93, 0.0341308}, {2, 1395.76, 
  0.0511362}, {2, 1456.59, 0.0326164}, {2, 1517.42, 0.0315381}, {2, 
  1578.28, 0.017776}, {2, 1639.24, 0.0254979}, {2, 1700.05, 
  0.00924619}, {2, 1760.98, 0.0225616}}
```

I also tried with ParametricNDSolveValue, in this way:

```
Sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
   S'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k2 ES[t],
  Eu'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k6 EP[t] + k2 ES[t],
   ES'[t] == k1 Eu[t] S[t] - (k2 + k3) ES[t],
   EP'[t] == k3 ES[t] - (k4 + k5 + k6) EP[t],
   Ec'[t] == k4 EP[t],
   P'[t] == k6 EP[t], S[0] == 100, Eu[0] == 0.5, 
   ES[0] == 0, EP[0] == 0, Ec[0] == 0, P[0] == 0}, {S, Eu,
    ES, EP, Ec, P}, {t, 0, 2000}, {k3,k4,k6}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
  PrecisionGoal -> Infinity]
```

followed by:

```
model[k3_,k4_, k6_][i_, t_] := 
  Through[Sol[k3,k4,k6][t], List][[i]] /;
   And @@ NumericQ /@ {k3, k4, k6,i, t};
```

Fitting again does not make any sense. Constraints also do not help. I tried with just k4>0, I left it overnight but NO fitting at all. I went through other questions, as I mentioned before, Manipulate my model gives reasonable "manual" fitting. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look into `ParametricNDSolveValue[]`.

Comment: I strongly second @J.M.'s suggestion. I think you need `ParametricNDSolve[]` or the `*Value` version for your system. Additionally, would you be able to post some sample data, or at least the reasonable values for the kinetic constants from your manual fit? It's hard to troubleshoot without trying to run some code.

Comment: Multiple potential duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21774/; and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28461/ and its many linked duplicates http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34807, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56318/, etc.  Are you sure your question is not addressed by any of these?

Comment: As @MichaelE2 also pointed out, [Oleksandr's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28527/27951) to a past question seems extremely relevant. You obviously are aware of it, since you seem to be using the same code structure he proposed. Could you show us perhaps some annotated fitting results, or otherwise give us an idea of what you are not satisfied with? Additionally, you could try and generate a "fake" data set to feed to your fitting procedure, to see if  you can recover the known parameters you used to generate the dataset.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I edited my post with more information. I went through every question @Michael E2 mentioned. I understand that a best option is ParametricNDSolveValue, but again I am missing some detail which I do not understand. Thanks!!

Comment: Just a minor advice but it really pays out to not use symbols in one's code that start with capital letters. By doing so there is complete safety as of not interfering with Mathematica's definitions. Eg. variables C or D or N already demonstrate the case.

Comment: @gwr thanks for your advice!

Comment: Hi! Brief update: I used ParametricNDSolveValue to solve the ODE system, then I generated some fake data putting some random error. From k4=0.0013, k5=0.0001, k6=0.06, my NonLinearModelFit procedure gave me k4=0.21, k5=0.181 and k6=3.46. Very far from my initial ones!! Hope you can give me a hint! :)

Comment: I've grown very interested in this kind of problem. I'm glad to hear that you are still working on it. I have been working on Oleksandr's proposed code that I referenced in my previous comment, trying to do exactly what you just did, and I also am having trouble reproducing known parameters... I want to take a few more hours to check that I haven't done something silly with my code, but if I can't figure this out, I was planning to try and get Oleksandr involved as well.

Comment: Hi @MarcoB: sounds good to me, I am still working on it, and believe that it is an intriguing problem, since I have simulated and fitted even more complex kinetic, but never with more than one response.
Forcing ParametricNDSolveValue to use a method like "StiffnessSwitching" does not help either. I have also changed my fitting method to NMinimize, but it is still running. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. I hope it helps.

I used `ParametricNDSolveValue`

```
k1 = 20; k2 = 200; k3 = 0.03;
tmax = 2000;
ode = {S'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k2 ES[t], 
   Eu'[t] == -k1 Eu[t] S[t] + k6 EP[t] + k2 ES[t], 
   ES'[t] == k1 Eu[t] S[t] - (k2 + k3) ES[t], 
   EP'[t] == k3 ES[t] - (k4 + k5 + k6) EP[t], Ec'[t] == k4 EP[t], 
   P'[t] == k6 EP[t],
   S[0] == 100, Eu[0] == 0.5, ES[0] == 0, EP[0] == 0, Ec[0] == 0, 
   P[0] == 0};
paramSOL = ParametricNDSolveValue[ode,
   {Ec, EP, S, Eu, ES, P}, {t, 0, tmax}, {k4, k5, k6}];
```

Then, define

```
model[k4_, k5_, k6_][i_, t_] := 
  Through[paramSOL[k4, k5, k6][t], List][[i]] /; And @@ NumericQ /@ {k4, k5, k6, i, t};
```

And using `NonlinearModelFit`...

```
fitted = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[k4, k5, k6][i, t],
        {{k4, 0.1}, {k5, 0.1}, {k6, 0.1}}, {i, t}] // Quiet;

fitted["RSquared"]
fitted["ParameterTable"]
```

> RSquared = 0.990764

[image]

Plot of result:

```
dataEc = Take[data, 30][[All, 2 ;; 3]];
dataEP = Drop[data, 30][[All, 2 ;; 3]];
Show[
 ListPlot[{dataEc, dataEP}, PlotLegends -> {"Ec", "EP"},Frame -> True],
 Plot[ {fitted[1, t], fitted[2, t]}, {t, 0, tmax}] ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, that's fantastic! I am running it right now, it is taking some time...it seems to me that the error was in model definition, right? Thanks again, hope it will work now!

Comment: @BlueOysterCult That's weird. It takes like 2 seconds on my crappy machine. Note I made an edit, I forgot to put the value for `tmax`. One of the problems I saw was that you weren't specifying any starting points for the NonlinearModelFit to work properly. That might be why you were getting odd results.

Comment: Hi @Ivan, it is working fine know, even with more complex model. And no, I tried with initial guesses too and it was the same. I think that the order of the different variable in ParametricNDSolveValue makes a difference. I mean, you specify ParametricNDSolveValue[ode, {EP, Ec, etc...}...] and your data need to be data=List[EP, Ec], in the same order!! I changed the order in your script, and it went odd again! :) Thanks!! –

Comment: @BlueOysterCult That's exactly right! The order of the solutions of any solver is given by the order specified in the input. And in the model function the `i` variable is the index of the solution you are extracting, so 1 is Ec and 2 is EP.