# Simultaneous fitting of ParametricNDSolve with varying initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

**Edit: Issue solved - code at end**

I am fitting 3 enzyme kinetics data sets. They are all from the same enzyme, but with different initial conditions. I am unsure of how to simultaneously fit 3 different `ParametricNDSolve` containing different initial conditions simultaneously using `NonlinearModelFit`.

The data sets are:

```
data0={{1, 0.14}, {2, 0.29}, {3, 0.45}, {24, 2.21}};
i0=4.5;
data200={{1, 2.65}, {2, 3.63}, {3, 4.25}, {24, 5.40}};
i200=5.97;
data2000={{1, 4.17}, {2, 4.80}, {3, 4.99}, {24, 5.24}};
i2000=5.39;
```

I'm fitting it to the following system of differential equations:

```
eS'[t]==-k1*eS[t]-k2*eS[t]*G[t],
G'[t]==-k2*eS[t]*G[t],
eG'[t]==k2*eS[t]*G[t],
e'[t]==k1*eS[t],
eT'[t]==k1*eS[t]+k2*eS[t]*G[t]
```

The data points correspond to `eT[t]`. In regards to the initial conditions, the following remain constant between the 3 data sets:

```
eG[0]==0,
e[0]==0,
eT[0]==0
```

However, two of the initial conditions change depending on the data set. For `data0`,

```
eS[0]==i0,
G[0]==0
```

For `data200`,

```
eS[0]==i200,
G[0]==200
```

For `data2000`,

```
eS[0]==i2000,
G[0]==2000
```

For any individual data set, I know how to find a fit for the parameters `k1` and `k2` as follows (for `data200`):

```
par200=ParametricNDSolve[{
eS'[t]==-k1*eS[t]-k2*eS[t]*G[t],
G'[t]==-k2*eS[t]*G[t],
eG'[t]==k2*eS[t]*G[t],
e'[t]==k1*eS[t],
eT'[t]==k1*eS[t]+k2*eS[t]*G[t],
eG[0]==0,
e[0]==0,
eT[0]==0,
eS[0]==i200,
G[0]==200},
{eG,e,eT,eS},{t,0,24},{k1,k2}];

fit=NonlinearModelFit[data200,{eT[k1,k2][t]/.par200,k1>0,k2>0},{k1,k2},t,Method->"NMinimize"];
```

I can obtain values for `k1` and `k2` for each data set individually, but I would like to fit for `k1` and `k2` from all 3 data sets simultaneously. I was thinking of merging all three data sets together and identifying them by a dummy variable as follows:

```
data=Join[
data0/.{t_,y_}->{1,t,y},
data200/.{t_,y_}->{2,t,y},
data2000/.{t_,y_}->{3,t,y}];
```

However, then I get stuck: I'm not sure how to setup the function in `NonlinearModelFit` such that only `eT[k1,k2][t]/.par0` is used when the dummy variable is 1, only `eT[k1,k2][t]/.par200` is used when the dummy variable is 2, etc...

I've seen the following answers in stackexchange: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84063/ode-fitting-to-dataset) and [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/866/simultaneously-fitting-multiple-datasets), but both are trying to fit data sets where either the initial conditions aren't changing or `ParametricNDSolve` isn't used. I've been unsuccessful at trying to adapt the answers for either to tackle my issue.

Thanks for any help.

**Solution**
So basically, use of `KroneckerDelta` basically solves everything. Assuming that `par0` is setup analogous to `par200` above,

```
model0[index_,t_,k1_,k2_]=KroneckerDelta[index,1]*eT[k1,k2][t]/.par0;
model200[index_,t_,k1_,k2_]=KroneckerDelta[index,2]*eT[k1,k2][t]/.par200;
model[index_,t_,k1_,k2_]=model0[index, t, k1, k2]+model200[index, t, k1, k2];

fit=NonlinearModelfit[data,{model[index,t,k1,k2],k1>0,k2>0},{k1,k2},{index,t},Method->"NMinimize"];
```

This will fit the `data0` and `data200` data sets simultaneously. If you want to fit all 3 data sets, include the corresponding code for `par2000` and `model2000`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Few new users immediately provide full info in correct style, so well done. You have made a syntax error in fifth line of first code block. Be sure to accept the answer (if any) which solves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

A solution can be obtained, roughly following the approach in [question 84063](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84373/1063).  Recast the `data` and, for convenience, the initial conditions as,

```
data = Join[Join[{1}, #] & /@ data0, Join[{2}, #] & /@ data200, 
    Join[{3}, #] & /@ data2000];
init = {{i0, 0}, {i200, 200} , {i2000, 2000}};
```

Then, solutions to the ODEs are given by

```
par = (ParametricNDSolveValue[{eS'[t] == -k1*eS[t] - k2*eS[t]*G[t], 
    G'[t] == -k2*eS[t]*G[t], eG'[t] == k2*eS[t]*G[t], 
    e'[t] == k1*eS[t], eT'[t] == k1*eS[t] + k2*eS[t]*G[t], 
    eG[0] == 0, e[0] == 0, eT[0] == 0, eS[0] == First@#, G[0] == Last@#}, 
    eT, {t, 0, 24}, {k1, k2}] & /@ init) // Flatten;
```

(only `eT` needs to be stored), the `model` by

```
model[k1_, k2_][i_, t_] := par[[i]][k1, k2][t] /; And @@ NumericQ /@ {k1, k2, i, t}];
```

and finally the fitted solution by

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[k1, k2][i, t], {{k1, .03}, {k2, .002}}, {i, t}];
fit["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]

```
Show[Plot[{fit[1, t], fit[2, t], fit[3, t]}, {t, 0, 24}], 
    ListPlot[{data0, data200, data2000}]]
```

[image]

More data points presumably would yield a better fit, although the one obtained is not bad.