# Getting errors in NonlinearModelFit

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, parametric-functions, nonlinear

I need to fit a system of ODEs to data. The solutions which could work for me are given in the following posts

[How to fit 3 data sets to a model of 4 differential equations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28461/how-to-fit-3-data-sets-to-a-model-of-4-differential-equations)
[ODE fitting to dataset](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84063/ode-fitting-to-dataset#new-answer?newreg=2453808133514378a0d43a4be8651855)

However, when I reran both solutions proposed in those threads and apparently accepted by the community as working and valid, I got a series of errors (print after calling NonlinearModelFit). Could you please explain why? My understanding is that the model cannot return the values for A, B, or X depending on the value of the dummy variable i, but I don't know how to resolve the issue and why it appears in the first place.

The code follows below.

```
    a'[t] == -k1 a[t] b[t] + k2 x[t], a[0] == 1,
    b'[t] == -k1 a[t] b[t] + k2 x[t] - k3 b[t] x[t], b[0] == 1,
    x'[t] == k1 a[t] b[t] - k2 x[t] - k3 b[t] x[t], x[0] == 0
    }, {a, b, x}, {t, 0, 10}, {k1, k2, k3}
   ];

abscissae = Range[0., 10., 0.1];
ordinates = With[{k1 = 0.85, k2 = 0.15, k3 = 0.50},
   Through[sol[k1, k2, k3][abscissae], List]
  ];

data = ordinates + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1^2], Dimensions[ordinates]];
ListLinePlot[data, DataRange -> {0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]

transformedData = {
    ConstantArray[Range@Length[ordinates], Length[abscissae]] // Transpose,
    ConstantArray[abscissae, Length[ordinates]],
    data
   } ~Flatten~ {{2, 3}, {1}};

model[k1_, k2_, k3_][i_, t_] := 
  Through[sol[k1, k2, k3][t], List][[i]] /;
    And @@ NumericQ /@ {k1, k2, k3, i, t};

fit = NonlinearModelFit[
   transformedData,
   model[k1, k2, k3][i, t],
   {k1, k2, k3}, {i, t}
  ];

ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz: At t$2274999 == 2.683730722253005`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {2.7} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>
```

Comment: Post you refer is dated as 2013, and in that time there been version 8 or 9.  In every version some Automatic method used in `NDSolve`. Now in v.12 and 12.1 it is quite different method then in v. 8 and 9. What version you are running?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I am using 10.0.2.0 on Mac. Just to be sure, in your answer below you only added option Method in NonlinearModelFit? It now runs fine.

Comment: Yes, it runs fine in v.12.0.0. We can try several options but this one is good.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Regarding the method option in `NonlinearModelFit`, which ones are most suitable for problems with constraints? Is there any one which should be preferred (apart from Automatic)?

Comment: The method depends on constraints and equations we solve. It could be better you show us your particularly problem and we look how it could be solve.

Answer (score 6):

We can use some options to solve this problem

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{a'[t] == -k1 a[t] b[t] + k2 x[t], 
    a[0] == 1, b'[t] == -k1 a[t] b[t] + k2 x[t] - k3 b[t] x[t], 
    b[0] == 1, x'[t] == k1 a[t] b[t] - k2 x[t] - k3 b[t] x[t], 
    x[0] == 0}, {a, b, x}, {t, 0, 10}, {k1, k2, k3}
   ];

abscissae = Range[0., 10., 0.1];
ordinates = 
  With[{k1 = 0.85, k2 = 0.15, k3 = 0.50}, 
   Through[sol[k1, k2, k3][abscissae], List]];

data = ordinates + 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1^2], Dimensions[ordinates]];
ListLinePlot[data, DataRange -> {0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]

transformedData = {ConstantArray[Range@Length[ordinates], 
      Length[abscissae]] // Transpose, 
    ConstantArray[abscissae, Length[ordinates]], data}~
   Flatten~{{2, 3}, {1}};

model[k1_, k2_, k3_][i_, t_] := 
  Through[sol[k1, k2, k3][t], List][[i]] /; 
   And @@ NumericQ /@ {k1, k2, k3, i, t};

fit = NonlinearModelFit[transformedData, 
   model[k1, k2, k3][i, t], {k1, k2, k3}, {i, t}, 
   Method -> "Gradient"];
```

Now we check and plot

```
Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[fit[i, t], {i, 3}]], {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> {a, b, x}], 
 ListPlot[data, DataRange -> {0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]