# How to make the default table alignment "right"

Tags: formatting

The default table alignment is [`Center`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Center.html), however I would like to make it [`Right`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Right.html) so that [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixForm.html) by default returns a matrix with right-aligned entries. I have played around with the options inspector setting the option `Alignment(TableViewBoxOptions)` to `{Right, Bottom}`,
[image]

but it does not seem to produce any effect. Also, I noticed a button [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) in the options Inspector window, which is greyed and inactive??

Answer (score 1):

Within a session this should work:

```
SetOptions[MatrixForm, TableAlignments -> Right]
```

You can make this setting global and persistent by including it in your user `init.m` file.  This file is loaded by each Kernel as it is started.  You can find its location by evaluating:

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "kernel", "init.m"}]
```

Please make a back-up of this file before modifying it.  For more see: [Automatically load packages at startup](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8221/121) and [init.m documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/init.m.html)

`TableForm`, `MatrixForm`, and `Grid` use `GridBox`, but `GridBoxOptions` will be overruled by the individual Options of these formatting functions.

I believe that `TableViewBox` (along with `GridBox`) is used by the undocumented `TableView`:

```
 Array[Times, {5, 5}] // TableView
```

Also be aware that there is (or was) a bug in `TableForm`:  [TableAlignments -> Left not working](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7843/121)

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. I did not think of this alternative, and this will probably be sufficient for me. However, I am still intrigued by the question of how to make this the default behaviour globally, not just for a session or for a notebook. Thanks again.

Comment: @Emilio I'll update my answer with more specific instruction.